# Finding a tree that approximates the distances and total weights

Tags: algorithms, approximation

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ could we build a tree $T$ that approximates the distances from given vertex $r$ and the total weight, i.e. $\forall x \in V, d_G(r,x) \le d_T(r,x) \le 3 \cdot d_G(r,x)$ and $w(T) \le 3\cdot w(\text{MST}(G))$, where $\text{MST}$ is the minimum spanning tree and $w(\cdot)$ is the weight function i.e. $w:\Bbb E \to \Bbb R^+$. $d_G(v,u)$ denotes the shortest path distance between $v$ and $u$ in $G$, and $d_T(v,u)$ is the shortest path distance between $v$ and $u$ in $T$.

Could any one help me to understand how to build this tree and if there is any material that would help?

Comment: @FayezAbdlrazaqDeab: how would one construct the minimum spanning tree that you need to compare to?  Look up Prim's algorithm.

Comment: assume you build $T$ who much is it close to $MST$ ? or something like this ... I dont think you need to build it

Comment: @FayezAbdlrazaqDeab, as wandering logic mentioned, seems shortest path tree is 2 approximation, you can think about this and update your question with your thought.

Comment: this give us a perfect distances but how much it approximates the mst weight? it dosnt fulfill it! take a circle all weights are 1 and just one of them is n-2

Comment: In the circle you mentioned all of your inequalities are correct. p.s: with same argument you can prove is 2-approximation.

Comment: could you give me a proof to this 2 approximation ?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri no, the shortest path tree can be larger than the MST by a factor of $n(1-\epsilon)/2$ for any $\epsilon$. Consider a path of edges of weight 1, number the vertices $0$ to $n-1$, and add an edge of length $i/2$ between $0$ and $i$. the MST has weight $n-1$ and the shortest path tree has weight $n(n-1)/4$.

Comment: @SashoNikolov, I meant with similar argument, actually, I thought about it a little, and seems is not hard to obtain a 2 approximation by using the note I mentioned in my comment, when you find a cycle in MST (by combine it with shortest path for specific node) which has very smaller length in shortest path tree such that, does not exceed the limit, we can achieve a approximation guarantee (if you see my two different comments, at first I was thinking SPT is enough, after that I see is not hard to obtain by avoiding cycles in MST).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri it's really hard to guess that this is what you meant with your second comment. a simpler explanation will be interesting to me, even if it's less efficient. i am not sure what you mean by a 2-approximation (as there are two quantities to approximate) but the linked paper does not guarantee a 2-approximation to both quantities simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is solved in the following [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs.ds/0205045.pdf) by Khuller, Raghavachari, and Young. They show that you can construct a tree in which distances from the root are stretched by at most $\alpha$ and the total weight of the tree is at most $1 + 2/(\alpha - 1)$ times the weight of the MST. So, with $\alpha=3$, you can get $2$ times the weight of the MST. The algorithm does a depth-first traversal of the MST, and  adds paths from the shortest path tree when necessary, roughly speaking maintaining a shortest path structure in the current graph, which consists of the MST edges and the edges added from the shortest path three. Check the paper for details.

As I mentioned in the comment, there are graphs in which the weight of the shortest path tree rooted at some vertex is greater than the MST weight by $\Omega(n)$. One example is a path of unit weight edges, and edges from the first vertex in the path to the $i$-th vertex of weight just slightly less than $i-1$.